# Mouse scroll (scroll wheel) doesn't work in chrome for my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a landing page [here](https://oxinchannel.app/landing) which mouse scroll (scroll wheel) doesn't work on it but I can scroll on page by clicking on browser scrollbar and move it.
I had check it in other browser (Firefox) which was working fine even I checked it with several mobile devices and it was OK even in chrome !
This problem is just on chrome desktop version.
I'm using Ubuntu and chrome Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit).
Update 1 : scroll wheel stop working after page loads completely
Update 2 : I found that when you hover on the video which is on the page   it works fine ! and you can scroll with scroll wheel.

```js
//LOADER/SPINNER
$(window).bind("load", function() {

    "use strict";
    
    $(".spn_hol").fadeOut(1000);
});

// FIX HOME SCREEN HEIGHT
$(document).ready(function() {

    "use strict";
    
    setInterval(function() {

        "use strict";
        
        var widnowHeight = $(window).height();
        var containerHeight = $(".home-container").height();
        var padTop = widnowHeight - containerHeight;
        $(".home-container").css({
            'padding-top': Math.round(padTop / 2) + 'px',
            'padding-bottom': Math.round(padTop / 2) + 'px'
        });
    }, 10)
});







//OWL CAROSEL
$(document).ready(function() {

    "use strict";
    
    $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
        autoPlay: 3000,
        items: 4, //10 items above 1000px browser width
        itemsDesktop: [1370, 3], //5 items between 1000px and 901px
        itemsDesktopSmall: [900, 2], // betweem 900px and 601px
        itemsTablet: [600, 1], //2 items between 600 and 0
    });
});


    
 //PRETTYPHOTO

$(document).ready(function() {

    "use strict";

    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
        show_title: false,
        /* true/false */
    });
});



//WOW JS
$(document).ready(function() {

    "use strict";
 
    new WOW().init();
});



//RESPONSIVE VIDEO
$(document).ready(function() {

    "use strict";
    
    // Basic FitVids Test
    $(".video").fitVids();
});
```

```html
<?php /* Template Name: landing */ ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="اکسین‌چنل تنها اپلیکیشن آموزش زبان مورد تایید انجمن اروپاست، یادگیری زبان انگلیسی به شیوه تعاملی این نرم افزار را محبوب بیش از یک میلیون کاربر نموده است." />
  <meta name="keywords" content="یادگیری زبان" />
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
  <!-- Owl Carousel Assets -->
  <link href="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/css/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/css/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link href="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <!-- PrettyPhoto -->
  <link href="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/css/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <!-- Style -->
  <link href="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Responsive CSS -->
  <link href="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!— Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics —>
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-81897409-1"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
      dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-81897409-1');
  </script>
  <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
  <script>
    (function(w, d, s, l, i) {
      w[l] = w[l] || [];
      w[l].push({
        'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
        event: 'gtm.js'
      });
      var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j = d.createElement(s),
        dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
      j.async = true;
      j.src =
        'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
      f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-MQKXC9R');
  </script>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- PRELOADER -->
  <div class="spn_hol">
    <div class="spinner">
      <div class="bounce1"></div>
      <div class="bounce2"></div>
      <div class="bounce3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- END PRELOADER -->

  <!-- =========================
     START ABOUT US SECTION
============================== -->
  <section class="header  page" id="HOME">
    <h2></h2>
    <div class="section_overlay">


      <div class="container home-container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="logo text-center">
              <!-- LOGO -->
              <img width="250" height="110" src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/images/logo.png" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <div class="home_text">
              <!-- TITLE AND DESC -->
              <h1>اکسین چنل</h1>
              <p>یادگیری زبان با روش انجمن آموزش اروپا</p>
              <div class="download-btn">
                <!-- BUTTON -->
                <a class="btn home-btn wow fadeInLeft" href="#call_to_actiondl">دانلود</a>
                <a class="tuor btn wow fadeInRight" href="#ABOUT"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i> مشاهده امکانات</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-4">
            <div class="home-iphone">
              <img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/images/iPhone_Home.png" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- END HEADER SECTION -->




  <!-- =========================
     START ABOUT US SECTION
============================== -->



  <section>
    <div class="video_area">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 wow fadeInLeftBig">
            <!-- VIDEO LEFT TITLE -->
            <div id="ABOUT" class="video_title">
              <h2>اکسین‌چنل<br>را در عمل ببینید</h2>
              <p>در این ویدئوی کوتاه با مهمترین امکانات اکسین‌چنل آشنا شوید. روش منحصر به فرد آموزش در اکسین‌چنل شما را شگفت زده می‌کند…</p>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 wow fadeInRightBig">
            <!-- VIDEO -->
            <div class="video">
              <div id="15100491193757494">
                <div id="15105817321498355">
                  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://www.aparat.com/embed/M3fLp?data[rnddiv]=15105817321498355&data[responsive]=yes"></script>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="video-button-1">
        <!-- BUTTON -->
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-action" href="https://oxinchannel.app/%d8%ab%d8%a8%d8%aa-%d9%86%d8%a7%d9%85-%d8%a2%d9%86%d9%84%d8%a7%db%8c%d9%86/" role="button">همین حالا ثبت نام کنید</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="about page">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
          <!-- ABOUT US SECTION TITLE-->
          <div class="section_title">
            <h3>چرا اکسین‌چنل ؟</h3>
            <p>اکسین‌چنل با بیش از ۲ میلیون کاربر پر مخاطب ترین اپلیکیشن آموزش زبان است و توانسته است با متد منحصر بفرد خود کاربران بسیاری را موفق به یادگیری زبان کند. در حال حاضر اکسین‌چنل تنها اپلیکیشن آموزش زبان مورد تایید انجمن آموزش اروپاست و این نشان
              از کیفیت بالای آموزش در این اپلیکیشن است.
              <a target="_blank" class="moreinfotext" href="https://oxinchannel.app/%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%B1%D9%81%DB%8C-%D8%A7%DA%A9%D8%B3%DB%8C%D9%86-%DA%86%D9%86%D9%84/">اطلاعات بیشتر ...</a>
            </p>
          </div>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner_about_area">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="about_phone wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay=".5s">
              <!-- PHONE -->
              <img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/images/about_iphone.png" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6  wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay=".5s">
            <!-- TITLE -->
            <div class="inner_about_title">
              <h2>سرویس معلم خصوصی <br> تحولی در آموزش آنلاین</h2>
              <p>سرویس معلم خصوصی اکسین چنل این امکان را به شما میدهد تا برای یادگیری بهتر دروس، تمرین و تکرار از طریق اپلیکیشن با یک مدرس زبان حرفه‌ای در ارتباط باشید. <a class="moreinfotext" target="_blank" href="https://oxinchannel.app/%d9%85%d8%b9%d9%84%d9%85-%d8%ae%d8%b5%d9%88%d8%b5%db%8c-%d8%b2%d8%a8%d8%a7%d9%86/">اطللاعات بیشتر...</a>                </p>
              <div class="inner_about_desc">

                <!-- SINGLE DESC -->
                <div class="single_about_area fadeInUp wow" data-wow-duration=".5s" data-wow-delay="1s">
                  <!-- ICON -->
                  <!-- HEADING DESCRIPTION -->
                  <h3>مدرسین مورد تایید اکسین چنل</h3>
                  <p>مدرسینی که در این سرویس همکاری میکنند، دارای مدارک بین المللی آموزش زبان انگلیسی بوده و کیفیت آموزش آنها مورد تایید اکسین چنل است.</p>
                  <div><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i></div>

                </div>
                <!-- END SINGLE DESC -->


                <!-- SINGLE DESC -->
                <div class="single_about_area fadeInUp wow" data-wow-duration=".5s" data-wow-delay="1.5s">
                  <!-- ICON -->
                  <div><i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i></div>
                  <!-- HEADING DESCRIPTION -->
                  <h3>مکملی برای آموزش‌های اصلی اکسین‌چنل</h3>
                  <p>با تماشای ویدئوهای آموزشی اکسین چنل و انجام تمرینات روزانه اپ، مهارت‌های شنیداری و درک مطلب شما تقویت میشود و با سرویس معلم خصوصی مهارت های گفتاری و نوشتاری شما نیز تقویت میشوند.</p>
                </div>
                <!-- END SINGLE DESC -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </section>
  <!-- End About Us -->




  <section id="call_to_actiondl" class="subscribe" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.6" data-stellar-vertical-offset="20">
    <div class="section_overlay">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

            <!-- Start Subscribe Section Title -->
            <div class="section_title">
              <h2>دانلود اکسین چنل</h2>
              <div class="downloadsectuion">
                <a href="https://oxinchannel.app/downloads/apps/android/oxinchannel-app.apk" target="_self" rel="nofollow noopener"><img class="downloadsectuion2"  src="https://oxinchannel.app/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/directdownloadandroid-min.png" /></a>
                <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oxin.channel&amp;hl=en" target="_self" rel="nofollow noopener"><img class="downloadsectuion2"  src="https://oxinchannel.app/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/googleplay-min.png" /></a>
                <br><br>
                <a href="javascript:Boxzilla.show(22801);" target="_self" rel="nofollow noopener"><img class="downloadsectuion2"  src="https://oxinchannel.app/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/ios-appstore-min.png" /></a>
                <a href="https://oxinchannel.app/blog/oxin-channel-news/%D9%86%D8%B3%D8%AE%D9%87-%D8%AC%D8%AF%DB%8C%D8%AF-%D8%A7%DA%A9%D8%B3%DB%8C%D9%86%E2%80%8C%DA%86%D9%86%D9%84-%D9%88%DB%8C%DA%98%D9%87-ios-11-%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%87-%D8%B4%D8%AF/" target="_self"
                  rel="nofollow noopener"><img class="downloadsectuion2"  src="https://oxinchannel.app/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/ios-direct-min.png" /></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Subscribe Section Title -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

  </section>

  <!-- END SUBSCRIPBE FORM -->



  <!-- =========================
     START FEATURES
============================== -->
  <section id="FEATURES" class="features page">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
          <!-- FEATURES SECTION TITLE -->
          <div class="section_title wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1s">
            <h2>یادگیری زبان با متد روز اروپا</h2>
            <p>ویژگی‌های منحصر به فرد اکسین چنل شاید راه‌حل همان مشکلاتی باشند که تا امروز مانع شما برای یادگیری زبان شده‌اند. اگر این موارد برای شما مهم هستند، اکسین چنل قطعا مناسب شماست.</p>
          </div>
          <!-- END FEATURES SECTION TITLE -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="feature_inner">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 right_no_padding wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="1s">
            <!-- FEATURE -->

            <div class="left_single_feature">
              <!-- ICON -->
              <div><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></div>

              <!-- FEATURE HEADING AND DESCRIPTION -->
              <h3>هزینه پایین آموزش</h3>
              <p> هدف ما در اکسین‌چنل توسعه عدالت آموزشی است بنابر این هزینه های دوره های آموزشی اکسین‌چنل بسیار کمتر از هزینه های شرکت در کلاس‌های حضوری و یا روش‌های خودآموز زبان است. دوره های مختلف اکسین چنل و <a target="_blank" class="moreinfotext" href="https://oxinchannel.app/%d8%ab%d8%a8%d8%aa-%d9%86%d8%a7%d9%85-%d8%a2%d9%86%d9%84%d8%a7%db%8c%d9%86/">هزینه های آن را اینجا ببینید ...</a></p>
            </div>

            <!-- END SINGLE FEATURE -->


            <!-- FEATURE -->
            <div class="left_single_feature">
              <!-- ICON -->
              <div><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i></div>

              <!-- FEATURE HEADING AND DESCRIPTION -->
              <h3 style="direction:rtl;"> آموزش بر اساس CEFR </h3>
              <p>همراستا با معتبرترین سیستم رده بندی زبان آموزان در اروپا، اکسین چنل نیز دوره های خود را در سطوح A0، A1، A2 و B1 بر پایه سطح بندی CEFR ارائه میدهد. بدین ترتیب در هر جای جهان توانمندی زبانی شما قابل ارزیابی و استناد است. <a target="_blank"
                  class="moreinfotext" href="https://www.cambridgeenglish.org/exams-and-tests/cefr/">اطلاعات بیشتر...</a></p>
            </div>
            <!-- END SINGLE FEATURE -->


            <!-- FEATURE -->
            <div class="left_single_feature">
              <!-- ICON -->
              <div><i class="fa fa-address-card-o"></i></div>

              <!-- FEATURE HEADING AND DESCRIPTION -->
              <h3> اساتید نیتیو و بین‌المللی </h3>
              <p>برای تولید فیلم‌های آموزشی اکسین‌چنل بیش از ۷۰ مدرس نیتیو، ایرانی و بین‌المللی مشارکت داشته اند که همگی دارای مدارک معتبر آموزش زبان بوده‌اند. بنابراین میتوانید با اطمینان خاطر به آنچه این اساتید برای عرضه به شما دارند اعتماد کنید. </p>
            </div>
            <!-- END SINGLE FEATURE -->

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="feature_iphone">
              <!-- FEATURE PHONE IMAGE -->
              <img class="wow bounceIn info-image-section" data-wow-duration="1s" src="https://oxinchannel.app/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/info-site.png" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 left_no_padding wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="1s">

            <!-- FEATURE -->
            <div class="right_single_feature">
              <!-- ICON -->
              <div><i class="fa fa-certificate"></i></div>

              <!-- FEATURE HEADING AND DESCRIPTION -->
              <h3>دریافت مدرک معتبر</h3>
              <p>زبان آموزان اکسین چنل این امکان را خواهند داشت تا پس از تکمیل هر سطح، با پرداخت هزینه جداگانه، در آزمون پایان سطح برگزار شده توسط انجمن آموزش اروپا شرکت کنند و مدرک بین المللی دریافت کنند. <a target="_blank" class="moreinfotext" href="https://oxinchannel.app/%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%AF%DA%AF%DB%8C%D8%B1%DB%8C-%D8%B2%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AC%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%A2%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B2%D8%B4-%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%88%D9%BE%D8%A7/">با انجمن آموزش اروپا آشنا شوید ...</a></p>
            </div>
            <!-- END SINGLE FEATURE -->


            <!-- FEATURE -->
            <div class="right_single_feature">
              <!-- ICON -->
              <div><i class="fa fa-leanpub"></i></div>

              <!-- FEATURE HEADING AND DESCRIPTION -->
              <h3>یادگیری زبان کاربردی</h3>
              <p> بر خلاف روش‌های قدیمی آموزش زبان، در اکسین چنل انگلیسی را در قالب موضوعات کاربردی فرا میگیرید. بنابراین در اکسین چنل نیازی به یادگیری واژگان کم کاربرد یا نکات گرامری خسته کننده نخواهید داشت. <a target="_blank" class="moreinfotext" href="https://oxinchannel.app/%D8%A2%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B2%D8%B4-%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%B2%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%86%DA%AF%D9%84%DB%8C%D8%B3%DB%8C/">موضوعات آموزشی در اکسین چنل ...</a></p>
            </div>
            <!-- END SINGLE FEATURE -->


            <!-- FEATURE -->
            <div class="right_single_feature">
              <!-- ICON -->
              <div><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></div>

              <!-- FEATURE HEADING AND DESCRIPTION -->
              <h3>تنها ۱۰ دقیقه زمان در روز</h3>
              <p>در روش آموزشی اکسین‌چنل شما به صورت روزانه و مداوم در معرض آموزش های مختلف ویدئویی و تعاملی قرار میگیرید به همین دلیل سریعتر از سایر روش های قدیمی به زبان انگلیسی مسلط میشوید. با ۱۰ دقیقه زمان در روز میتوانید فیلمهای آموزشی هر روز را ببینید
                و تمرین آن روز را انجام دهید.</p>
            </div>
            <!-- END SINGLE FEATURE -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- END FEATURES SECTION -->



  <!-- =========================
     START CALL TO ACTION
============================== -->
  <div class="call_to_action call_to_action1">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row wow fadeInLeftBig" data-wow-duration="1s">
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <p class="diduhavequestiontl"> در کانال تلگرام اکسین بلاگ عضو شوید تا مطالب آموزشی رایگان اکسین چنل را به صورت روزانه دریافت کنید.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-action" href="http://t.me/oxinblog" role="button">عضویت در کانال تلگرام</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="call_to_action call_to_action2">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row wow fadeInLeftBig" data-wow-duration="1s">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-action" href="http://t.me/oxinblog" role="button">عضویت در کانال تلگرام</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <p class="diduhavequestiontl"> در کانال تلگرام اکسین بلاگ عضو شوید تا مطالب آموزشی رایگان اکسین چنل را به صورت روزانه دریافت کنید.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- END CALL TO ACTION -->


  <!-- =========================
     Start APPS SCREEN SECTION
============================== -->
  <section class="apps_screen page" id="SCREENS">
    <div class="screen_slider">
      <div id="demo" class="wow bounceInRight" data-wow-duration="1s">
        <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">

          <!-- APPS SCREEN IMAGES -->

          <div class="item">
            <a href="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/images/appdemo2.png" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/images/appdemo2.png" width="60" height="60" alt="APPS SCREEN" /></a>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <a href="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/images/appdemo3.png" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/images/appdemo3.png" width="60" height="60" alt="APPS SCREEN" /></a>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <a href="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/images/appdemo4.png" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/images/appdemo4.png" width="60" height="60" alt="APPS SCREEN" /></a>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <a href="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/images/appdemo5.png" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/images/appdemo5.png" width="60" height="60" alt="APPS SCREEN" /></a>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <a href="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/images/appdemo6.png" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/images/appdemo6.png" width="60" height="60" alt="APPS SCREEN" /></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>



  <!-- ENS APPS SCREEN -->





  <!-- =========================
     Start FUN FACTS
============================== -->


  <section class="fun_facts ">
    <div class="section_overlay">
      <div class="container wow bounceInLeft" data-wow-duration="1s">
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="single_fun_facts">
              <i class="pe-7s-albums"></i>
              <h2><span  class="counter_num">80</span> <span>+</span></h2>
              <p>موضوع کاربردی زبان انگلیسی</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="single_fun_facts">
              <i class="pe-7s-tools"></i>
              <h2><span  class="counter_num">30</span> <span>+</span></h2>
              <p>تیم پشتیبانی</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="single_fun_facts">
              <i class="pe-7s-global"></i>
              <h2><span  class="counter_num">70</span> <span>+</span></h2>
              <p>مدرس بین المللی</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="single_fun_facts">
              <i class="pe-7s-smile"></i>
              <h2><span  class="counter_num">2,100,000</span> <span>+</span></h2>
              <p>کاربر از سراسر جهان </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- END FUN FACTS -->

  <!-- =========================
     FOOTER
============================== -->

  <section class="copyright">
    <h2></h2>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row footersector">
        <div class="col-md-6 socialsections">
          <div class="scroll_top">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/oxinchannel" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-22413" src="https://oxinchannel.app/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/facebook-min.png" alt="" width="40" height="40"></a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/oxinchannel" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-22415" src="https://oxinchannel.app/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/instagram-min.png" alt="" width="40" height="40"></a>
            <a href="https://www.telegram.me/oxinchannel" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-22417" src="https://oxinchannel.app/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/telegram-min.png" alt="" width="40" height="40"></a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/organization/11025520" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-22417" src="https://oxinchannel.app/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/linkedin-min.png" alt="" width="40" height="40"></a>
            <a href="https://www.twitter.com/oxinchannel" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-22417" src="https://oxinchannel.app/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/twitter-min.png" alt="" width="40" height="40"></a>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUQW_sfuaAqNk5pRNhjVNlg" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-22417" src="https://oxinchannel.app/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/youtube-min.png" alt="" width="40" height="40"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 copy_right_textcl">
          <div class="copy_right_text">
            <!-- COPYRIGHT TEXT -->
            <a target="_blank" class="footerlinks" href="https://oxinchannel.app/%d8%a7%d8%b1%d8%aa%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%b7-%d8%a8%d8%a7-%d9%85%d8%a7/"><i class="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></i> تماس با اکسین چنل</a>
            <a target="_blank" class="footerlinks" href="https://t.me/oxinchannelCRM"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 پشتیبانی آنلاین</a>
          </div>

        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- END FOOTER -->


  <!-- =========================
     SCRIPTS
============================== -->


  <script src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/js/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/js/jquery.ajaxchimp.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/js/jquery.ajaxchimp.langs.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/js/wow.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/js/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/landing-assets/js/script.js"></script>

  <?php wp_footer(); ?>
  <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
  <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-MQKXC9R"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for helping me ...

Comment: You should isolate the problem and create Minimal Working Example, also if you have php code don't create SO snippet because no one will not be able to execute it.

Comment: Working example of what? I had add my codes to see first, I'm coding not just asking methodology question and second, you can see my code.

Comment: You can check the live site in link that I had mentioned in the question .

Comment: You need to create minimal example that can be reproducible, try removing stuff from your code and see if you will still have problem with scrolling when you remove something and the scroll will work it mean that the last thing you've removed was the root problem.

Comment: I had designed this page several month ago and since then I didn't make any change on it and suddenly today I understand this page have this problem .

Comment: Please create an [MCVE] emphasis on minimal

Comment: Try remove  https://www.aparat.com from your page maybe it's causing rocket loader to not initialize, there is some warnings from console in google chrome.

Comment: I had remove that and test! no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by rocket-loader.min.js

Comment: Can you please be more explicit and tell me whats the relation of this file with the error or how can I solve it? as I'm using WP rocket on all pages of my site and they are working fine !

Comment: I had see error of rocket-loader.min.js in console but I don't think this file cause the problem

Comment: @MohammadGhonchesefidi yes the plugin is adding event listener to scroll event and it's executing preventDefault untill it's initialized.

Comment: @MohammadGhonchesefidi [Rocket Loader breaking external scroll and scrollwheel](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/rocket-loader-breaking-external-scroll-and-scrollwheel-javascripts/19010)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had delete WP rocket plugin and test it and no luck.

Comment: By the way if it is adding prevent default so it shouldn't work in other browsers too. Am I right?

Comment: I'm trying in chrome and with removing the event listener in dev tools the mouse wheel work as expected